# Hover over another div when it comes to

Tags: html, css

when I hover over "Div2", I want the hover of "Div1" to work

```css
.Div1:hover{
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="Div1">Hello!</div>

<div class="Div2">Open hello!</div>
```

Comment: put div2 in div1...

Comment: thats not the way hover works, this question just seems lazy with no prior research done

Answer (score 1):

You can use display: flex on the container, then change the rendering order. Then you can hover on div2 and highlight div1.

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.div1, .div2 {
  flex: 0 0 100%;
}

.div1 { order: 1; }
.div2 { order: 2; }

.div2:hover ~ .div1 {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="div2">hello!</div>
  <div class="div1">open hello!</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can choose one class for both to make hoover works for both.

```css
.DivHoover:hover{
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="Div1 DivHoover">Hello!</div>

<div class="Div1 DivHoover">Open hello!</div>
```

Comment: the code doesnt work]

Comment: No, that's not what I meant, as for Div2, I want Div1 to work